# Upload limit exceeded when uploading to Youtube through API while can upload backstage

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Our application is returning the following error message shown when our clients uploaded videos through our API (please see the figure attached below),

The client is able to upload videos himself through YouTube

[image: error code]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take your time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, edit your post, adding to it relevant missing information. Please obey to SO guidelines: [don't post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8327971), but ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) plain text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited number of videos you can upload via the API per day no matter what your quota may be.  This does not effect the number of videos you can upload though Googles YouTube Web application.  This limit is strictly for API usage.

I believe that number is currently twenty but it has changed several times in the past.  You should wait until tomorrow and try again.

You can find the doucmentation for this error message here [videos_youtube.videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.insert)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Wondering how can we increase the upload limit via API, like around 100 per user per day similar to that via the YouTube Web App... Much appreciated.

Comment: You cant this is a hard limit.